# Regex that can match [k=v] with recursion?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I'm looking to write a Python2 regex for the following case. **I haven't done a feasibility analysis yet**:

- example_input_string: `the quick [brown_1=fox] jumps over the [lazy=dog]`
- list_of_regex_matches: `["[brown_1=fox]", "[lazy=dog]"]`

Basically, I'd like to match all `[\w+=.*]` substrings, and output them in a list. It seems like the API that I'd want to use here is `re.findall`, but what is the right regex for this in Python2?

In this specific case, the substrings `[brown_1=fox]` and `[lazy=dog]` individually match the regex: `[\w+=.*]`.

**NOTE:**
The following input strings are ALLOWED: `the quick [brown=[fox[a=b][c=d]]] jumps over`. i.e. within a single element that matches `[\w+=.*]`, the `[`, `]` and `=` characters could occur again. But it is guaranteed that BEFORE the first "equals" character, there are only alpha-numeric characters and underscores.

Comment: I've a hunch this is not possible with a single (non-Perl) regex.

Comment: "regex ... with recursion" is going to require esoteric regex features that Python doesn't have.

Comment: [`r'\[\w+=(?:[^][]++|(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*]))*]'`](https://rextester.com/ILDF99336) with PyPi regex module.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the alternative [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), which supports the recursion pattern  [`(?R)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), so that you can use the `findall()` method like this:

```
import regex
s = 'the quick [brown=[fox[a=b][c=d]]] jumps over the [lazy=dog]'
print(regex.findall(r'\[(?>[^[\]]|(?R))*\]', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['[brown=[fox[a=b][c=d]]]', '[lazy=dog]']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple state machine for this

```
def parse(s):
    stack = []
    parts = []
    current = []
    for c in s:
      if c == "[":
        current.append("")
        stack.append(c)
      elif c == "]" and stack:
        stack.pop()
        parts.insert(0,current.pop())
      elif stack:
        current[-1] += c
    return parts

print(parse("the quick [brown=[fox[a=b][c=d]]] jumps over"))
# ['brown=', 'fox', 'c=d', 'a=b']
```